# executing shell script from launcher, slow to end/complete the script

Tags: shell-script, desktop-environment, xrandr, unity

I am using a bash script to rotate my screen via xrandr. 
To make it easier to use I added the script to the unity launcher.

The problem I have encountered with this is that the script seems to execute fast but has a really long "shutdown" period when started through the launcher.

After activating the launcher icon the script gets executed, finishes (atleast I think it finished, because it only turns the screen) and then the launcher icon blinks for around 5 seconds in which I can't restart the script to get another rotation.

When calling the script from a terminal there is no additional "shutdown" time.

My .desktop file looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Name=scrota
Icon=/usr/share/icons/icon.png
Exec=/home/user/scrota
```

Edit: 
This is the script

```
#!/bin/bash

scrState=`xrandr | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 | cut -d " " -f 5`

case "$scrState" in
    "(normal") xrandr -o left
        ;;
    "left") xrandr -o inverted
        ;;
    "inverted") xrandr -o right
        ;;
    "right") xrandr -o normal
        ;;
    *)  echo "error"
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: What's the script?